# Read Data from data set

Tags: c#

I have data set that is being filled from sql query, like this

```
cmd_sql.CommandText = " SELECT BrDok " +
                      " FROM ordersstavke " +
                      " WHERE SifParFil = '" + rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "'";

MySqlDataAdapter sql_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_sql);
DataSet ds_dok = new DataSet("ordersstavke");
sql_adapter.Fill(ds_dok);
```

Now I want to extract value from data set for sql update, like this one

```
myQuery = "UPDATE ordersstavke " +
          "SET BrDok = '" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', " +
          "SifParFil = '" + rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "', " +
          "WHERE BrDok = " + ds_dok.Tables["ordersstavke"].Rows[0]["BrDok"] + "'";
```

I tried this `ds_dok.Tables["ordersstavke"].Rows[0]["BrDok"]` but I got an error,
I was thinking to do something like this

```
string BrDok;
BrDok  = ds_dok.["BrDok"].ToString();
```

But nothing, how to extract that BrDok or just put it into procedure?

Thanks infront!

Comment: what is the error you got here? Please, accept the answers of previous questions, if they helped you.

Comment: Shitti error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you read the answers to your previous questions? Same error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a string argument for the dataset class, then it will be the dataset name and not the datatable name. And there is no table in the database with name you provided for a dataset, so give it while filling the dataset. Write some thing like below.

```
DataSet ds_dok = new DataSet();
sql_adapter.Fill(ds_dok,"ordersstavke");
```

and you can write all the remaining code as it is in your code part.

And your second update query has some syntax error, see it like below

```
myQuery = "UPDATE ordersstavke " +           "SET BrDok = '" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', "
 +           "SifParFil = '" + rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "', " +           "WHERE BrDok 
 = '" + ds_dok.Tables["ordersstavke"].Rows[0]["BrDok"] + "'";
```

You forgot to put an starting inverted comma at the **where** clause.

Comment: I still have an error with syntax, but i added inverted comma at the where clause.

Comment: Got it, I had a comma before WHERE, I need to start better looking at the code. THANKS ALL

Comment: vot to undelete this question if you have rights to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480605/parameters-and-coding/10480638#10480638

Comment: @PranayRana, why you are asking to undelete???? You have more reputation than me, you only can do it right?

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala - because its answered , have 5 votes on it and except formatting question is good too for beginner thats y .....

Comment: sorry, but the question is removed from the stack overflow. If its not removed, i can reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
 DataSet ds_dok = new DataSet("ordersstavke");
 sql_adapter.Fill(ds_dok,"BrDok");
```

Then use

```
ds_dok.Tables["BrDok"].Rows[0]["BrDok"].ToString()
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but I got an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE BrDok = '565'' at line 1

Comment: @CrBruno, see the query modification in the code i have given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ds_dok.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BrDok"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small hint to the sql-command. You should use sql-parameters to prefent sql-injection.