# How do I solve this compile error?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I'm getting this compile error message.  How do I solve it?

> Error 28  'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition 
>   for 'Parameters' and no extension method 'Parameters' accepting a first argument of 
>   type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using 
>   directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\cofex\Desktop\Gestion de salair - 
>   pompier - ARAB - Copy - Copy\Gestion de salair - pompier - ARAB - Copy - 
>   Copy\WindowsFormsApplication1\Classes\employeurclass.cs 152 26
>       WindowsFormsApplication1

On this code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (query, _connection); // Form1.connection.Open(); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Securite_Social", N_Securite_Social);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_CCP", N_CCP);
```

Comment: I would start on fixing error #1, not #28.

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: That's not a question, that's just an error message. Is the question that you don't understant the error message?

Comment: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (query, _connection);
                // Form1.connection.Open();
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Securite_Social", N_Securite_Social);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_CCP", N_CCP);

Comment: Thats the msg i receive it and the q?is this sqlcmd doesnt know the cmd and when i type it the whole line goes red underlined sorry guys im knew to the C#

Comment: i have add the sys.designer and sys.mangmt referrance and still the same prblem thnx aphelion

Comment: It appears that you have created your own class called SqlCommand which conflicts with the SqlCommand class in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Comment: I voted to undelete on the assumption that @hans's edit made this into a complete question.

Comment: I also voted to reopen for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

add

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

namespace to your file